# Custom grid line in a Flex Chart?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am using the standard Flex 3 BubbleChart component and I would like to customize a couple of the grid lines separately from the rest.

I would like to highlight a gridline in the X-direction as well as in the Y-direction to show a quadrant.

Is there any way to customize the look and feel of a subset of gridlines within a Flex chart (i.e. bubble chart)?

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check out this two nice articles:

- [Using chart grid lines](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7c45.html)
- [Drawing on chart controls](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7c44.html)

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply.  I will look into these.  I'm assuming that even though these are Flex 4 links that this code still applies for Flex 3.